# PowerShellでZabbixをインストールする方法

Tags: windows, powershell

PowerShellでZabbixをインストールしたいです。
コマンドプロンプトでは以下のコマンドでインストールできることは確認しました。

```
zabbix_agentd.exe -i -c zabbix_agentd.conf
```

また、PowerShellでは以下のコマンドでインストールexeを実行できるそうです。

```
Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe -ArgumentList test.txt -Wait
```

Start-ProcessコマンドにZabbixインストールに使用する設定ファイルを指定するcオプションを指定し、インストールを実施するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

使ったことはありませんが、以下のページが参考になるかと思います。

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/6b8149c2-1bc6-41c3-a1e0-c0eceac6fdda/startprocess?forum=powershellja

今回の場合ですと、

```
Start-Process -FilePath zabbix_agentd.exe -ArgumentList "-i","-c",zabbix_agentd.conf -Wait
```

でいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

zabbix_agent.exe と zabbix_agentd.conf のパスをフルパスで

`C:\hoge\zabbix_agentd.exe -i -c C:\moge\zabbix_agentd.conf`

のように書いてみてはどうでしょう？